# Replace repeating values with 0

Tags: r

I want to replace the repeating values in my data frame with 0. Some number of repetition is allowed.

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,9,9,150,220,220)
```

In the case the allowed number of repetition is let's say 4. The expected solution  should look like:

```
a_new<-c(1,2,3,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,9,9,150,220,220)
```

More than 4 times repeated values are replaced with 0.

Using the rle

```
b<-rle(a)
```

I can identify the number of repetition

```
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:8] 1 1 1 3 5 2 1 2
  values : num [1:8] 1 2 3 4 5 9 150 220
```

And replace it with 0

```
b$values[b$lengths>4]<-0

Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:8] 1 1 1 3 5 2 1 2
  values : num [1:8] 1 2 3 0 0 9 150 220
```

The question is how to instert the repetitions in this case the 0 back into the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `inverse.rle`

```
a_new<-c(1,2,3,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,9,9,150,220,220)

b <- rle(a_new)

b$values[b$lengths>4]<-0

inverse.rle(b)

[1]   1   2   3   4   4   4   0   0   0   0   0   9   9 150 220 220
```

Comment: Inverse.rle exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You may also achieve that in one line with

```
with(rle(a), rep(values * (lengths <= 4), lengths))
# [1]   1   2   3   4   4   4   0   0   0   0   0   9   9 150 220 220
```

so that we are operating inside `rle(a)` and are directly performing a modification of `inverse.rle`:

```
inverse.rle
# function (x, ...) 
# {
#     if (is.null(le <- x$lengths) || is.null(v <- x$values) || 
#         length(le) != length(v)) 
#         stop("invalid 'rle' structure")
#     rep.int(v, le) # The same except for le <= 4
# }
# <bytecode: 0x10470b4a8>
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way via `ave`,

```
a[ave(a, a, FUN = length) > 4] <- 0
a
#[1]   1   2   3   4   4   4   0   0   0   0   0   9   9 150 220 220
```

Comment: `rle` is important I think. For this `a<-c(1, 1, 2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,9,9,150,1, 1, 1)` it would incorrectly transform 1's to 0's.

Comment: Not clear actually. OP says repeating but then tries to work it with `rle`. I ll leave it up until they clarify

Answer (score 1):

Also a possibility:

```
(a != rle(a)$values[rle(a)$lengths > 4]) * a

 [1]   1   2   3   4   4   4   0   0   0   0   0   9   9 150 220 220
```

Answer (score 1):

With `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
data.table(a)[, a1 := if(.N >4) 0 else a, rleid(a)]$a1
#[1]   1   2   3   4   4   4   0   0   0   0   0   9   9 150 220 220
```